# Centering, and vertical aligning to bottom for div not working, CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one inside of another. I'm trying to center and vertical align the div on the inside to the bottom, but it's not working at all for some reason. Please take a look at my code:

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 500px;
}

#inner {
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline;
vertical-align: bottom;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'> 
<div id = 'inner'> inner </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `text-align:center` to center the inline div, then use absolute or fixed positioning on the inner div with a relative position on the outer div to affix it to the bottom:

```css
    #outer {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 500px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;

}

#inner {
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
bottom:0
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'> 
<div id = 'inner'> inner </div>
</div>
```

EDIT

You could wrap the content in another element and use margin:0 auto on an inline or inline-block:

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 500px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;

}

#inner {
width:100%;
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

#innerContent{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'> 
    <div id = 'inner'>
        <div id='innerContent'>hesisaveylongstringloremipsum<br>
          <input type='submit'>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or You can remove `text-align:center` if text would not be centered into `#outer` `div` and in `#inner` add `left:50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` and inner div will be centered.

Comment: But it messes up if there's anything in the inner div that's not text. For example, what if I want to but an input submit inside the inner div? <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit something'>

Comment: @nelek You should post an answer.

Comment: @frosty posted, little late :/ ;)

Comment: That's not centering as well, try changing "inner" for "thesisaveylongstringloremipsum" and you will see

Comment: I've edited the answer to resolve the text-align:center issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is little bit different solution with `transform` without using `text-align:center` (if text would not be centered) in `outter` `div` and avoiding `margin:0 auto;` in `#inner` `div`.

```css
#outer {
border: 1px solid black;
height: 500px;
position:relative;
}

#inner {
border: 1px solid black;
display: inline;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:50%; 
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id = 'outer'> 
<div id = 'inner'> <input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit something'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you're not actually centering it, just putting its left side in the half of the width.

Comment: @Vitim.us Yes, that's correct... but my answer is based on frosty comment about what if in `#inner` `div` isn't text but, for example, button.